# Angular.js - Don't sync $scope's value in process

Tags: angularjs, scope, loading

I want to show process status in page. Before start process, i set $scope's value true. So must showed **loading** in page, but in process's time page locked and don't show **loading**.

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.impFile=function(){
         $scope.processStatus= false;
         reader.readAsText(target.files[0]);

         reader.onload = function (e) {
             // start process, that take about 10 seconds
         }
         reader.onloadend = function () {
            $scope.processStatus= false;
         }
     }
});
```

Html:

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="processStatus"></i>
<span ng-hide="processStatus">uploaded</span>
```

Comment: can you please clarify what you wish to solve?

Comment: You need to show more code. Specifically, we can't tell if your process  that takes 10 seconds is happening synchronously or asynchronously. It sounds like you are doing it synchronously, and that would be one reason the scope is never updated.

Comment: @scniro i wish show loading in import csv. When i import take 10 seconds,  and in this gap time i want to show loading for user.

Comment: reader.onloadend is not under angular control, you have to wrap inner code with $timeout or $evalAsync or $applyAsync or something that trigger digest cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I add $scope.$apply in ***reader.onloadend*** function.

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.impFile=function(){
         $scope.processStatus= false;
         reader.readAsText(target.files[0]);

         reader.onload = function (e) {
             // start process, that take about 10 seconds
         }
         reader.onloadend = function () {
            $scope.processStatus= false;
         }
         //This is solution
         reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            $scope.csvFile.uploadStatus = false;
            $scope.$apply();
         }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using FileReader (where you can check the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

So what you can do is set $scope.processStatus to true when your reader starts reading a file:

```
reader.onloadstart = function() {
    $scope.processStatus = true;
}
```

And then when your reader is done reading a file, you can use the function you already have for reader.onloadend.

If you look at the documentation, reader.onload only occurs after a read operation is completed.

**Be careful though, the difference between reader.onloadend and reader.onload is that reader.onloadend will fire both success or failure, whereas reader.onload will fire only on success**